# How can I create a relation in Strapi if I don't know the id of the field?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I am creating a collection of judges and courthouses. Every judge will be assigned to one courthouse. I have set up my relation to be that courthouse has many judges[image: judge-to-courthouse]

I am attempting to do this programmatically when the app loads. I have a function that is able to populate all the fields in judge *except* the relation to courthouse. My function uses the Strapi API like this

```
const judge = await strapi.query('judge').create({
  name: data[i].name,
},
{
  courthouse: data[i].courthouse_name // here is where I think the relation is created
}
)
```

I am passing in a string that has the name of courthouse, because I don't know the ID of the courthouse in the Courthouse collection.

My question is it possible to create a relation to another collection by anything other than an ID? How can I create a relation to a courthouse by its name?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way around building a relationship between two models without the ID, so I created a custom solution using the [Strapi lifecycle hooks](https://strapi.io/blog/content-modelling-bite-sized-guide)

Essentially what I did I utilized the `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook to query and find the courthouse that matches the name like this:

```
// judges.js 
async beforeCreate(result, data) {
  const courthouse = await strapi.query('courthouse').find(
     {courthouse_name:data.courthouse}
  ); // returns the courthouse that matches the name
  result['courthouse'] = courthouse[0].id; // populates the relational field with the 
  // ID of the courthouse
}
```

The response object contained the courthouse's ID and I manipulated the data that is being sent to the create command like this:

```
const judge = await strapi.query('judge').create({
  name: data[i].name,
  courthouse: data[i].courthouse_name
})
```

The result is an object that looks like this:

`{name: 'Garfield Lucas, courthouse: 7463987}`